# Rust: how to convert SocketAddr to IpNetwork?

Tags: postgresql, rust, rust-diesel, rust-rocket

Using Diesel and Rocket I want to be able to log IPs that requests are coming from. [Here](https://www.reddit.com/r/rust/comments/84bdit/how_do_you_work_with_ip_addresses_here_ipaddr/) is the similar discussion, but without conclusion. Diesel maps Postgres `inet` type to `IpNetwork`, but Rocket returns `SocketAddr` from the request data. How to convert `SocketAddr` to `IpNetwork`?

**models.rs**:

```
#![allow(proc_macro_derive_resolution_fallback)]
use crate::schema::bs_date_forecast;

use chrono::{NaiveDate, NaiveDateTime};
use ipnetwork::IpNetwork;
use diesel::prelude::*;

#[derive(Queryable, Insertable, Serialize, Deserialize)]
#[table_name="bs_date_forecast"]
pub struct BsDateForecast {
    pub id: Option<i32>,
    pub predicted_date: NaiveDate,
    pub seer_ip: IpNetwork,
    pub created_timestamp: NaiveDateTime,  // Defined automatically at the database level
}

impl BsDateForecast {
    pub fn create(forecast: BsDateForecast,
                  conn: &PgConnection) -> Vec<BsDateForecast> {
        diesel::insert_into(bs_date_forecast::table)
            .values(&forecast)
            .get_results(conn)
            .expect("Error creating record")
    }
}
```

**routes.rs**:

```
#[post("/predictions", format = "application/json", data = "<prediction>")]
pub fn create(prediction: Json<BsDateForecast>,
              conn: DbConn,
              user_ip: SocketAddr) -> Json<Vec<BsDateForecast>> {
    let insert = BsDateForecast{
        id: None,
        seer_ip: user_ip.to_string(),  // How to get IpNetwork here???
        ..prediction.into_inner()
    };
    Json(BsDateForecast::create(insert, &conn))
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The INET type can store a subnet (including subnet mask) or a single host. The IpNetwork type is meant to store a subnet, but a single host can be stored the Postgres way, by specifying a full-length prefix.

A SocketAddr is an IpAddr plus a port number.

So the conversion is: get the IP part of the SocketAddr, create an IpNetwork from that by specifying the correct prefix.

The complication here is that the prefix is different for IP4 and IP6.

```
fn socket_addr_to_ip_network(socket_addr: &SocketAddr) -> IpNetwork {
  let ip = socket_addr.ip();
  IpNetwork::new(ip, single_host_prefix(ip))
    .expect("single_host_prefix created invalid prefix")
}
fn single_host_prefix(ip_addr: &IpAddr) -> u8 {
  match ip_addr { &IpAddr::V4(_) => 32, &IpAddr::V6(_) => 128 }
}
```